# Сохранение и открытие данных в файл из dataGridView

Tags: c#, файлы, файловая-система, вывод

Всем здравствуйте, вопрос следующий.К программе на с# подключена БД из  Microsoft SQL Server, в DataGridView  выводится таблица. Как сохранить данные из грида  в файл, а затем  и открыть?
 На просторах интернета я нашёл код,как сохранить ,он работает,вот:

```
                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\1.txt", FileMode.Create);
                        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
                        try
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    streamWriter.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value + "     ");
                                }
                            streamWriter.WriteLine();
                            }
                            streamWriter.Close();
                            fs.Close();
                             MessageBox.Show("Файл успешно сохранен");
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при сохранении файла!");
                        }
```

А как теперь открыть этот сохранённый файл?Я пробовал вот так,но не работает:

```
FileStream fStream = new FileStream(@"D:\1.txt", FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fStream);
            string[] str;
            int numberOfRows = 0;
            try
            {
                string[] str1 = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split('$');
                numberOfRows = str1.Count();
                dataBase.RowCount = numberOfRows - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows - 1; i++)
                {
                    str = str1[i].Split('#');
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataBase.ColumnCount; j++)
                    {
                        dataBase.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = str[j];
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при открытии файла!");
            }
```

Comment: При чтении вы делаете split по символам `$` и `#`. Между тем при записи не видно, чтобы вы добавляли такие символы.

Comment: @ AlexanderPetrov  а как правильно сплит убрать? Под не работает подразумеваю, что не происходит открытие файла с данными,пишет "  Ошибка при открытии файла!", именно то,что у меня в блоке catch

Comment: Если бы файл не открывался, то до блока try-catch вообще бы не дошло, исключение было бы выброшено раньше. Поставьте в MessageBox вывод ошибки, а не собственное сообщение.

Comment: @ AlexanderPetrov  можно поподробней пожалуйста,как туда поставить вывод ошибки?

Comment: `catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e); }`

Comment: @ AlexanderPetrov теперь ругается на эти строчки кода: 
Ошибка CS1503 Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "System.Exception" в "string".
Ошибка CS0136 Локальная переменная или параметр с именем "e" нельзя объявить в данной области, так как это имя используется во включающей локальной области для определения локальной переменной или параметра

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93802/discussion-between-roman-and-alexander-petrov).